# Exiting out of or quitting an actionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm creating the generic Battleships game in java and am currently making the GUI, I have set the GUI so that the user is entering the locations into a JTextField and then clicking a Button which does Label.getText() my code is as follows.

```js
        int state = 0;

        if (state == 0) {
          System.out.println("How many Submarines would you like");
          label1.setText("How many Submarines would you like");
          button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String subsString = textField1.getText();
              int subs = Integer.parseInt(subsString);
              for (int i = 0; i < subs; i++) {
                ship.add(new Ship("Sub", 1));
                CPUship.add(new CPUShip("Sub", 1));
                System.out.println("Added Sub");
              }
              label1.setText("How many Friggates would you like");
            }
          });
          state = 1;
        }

        if (state == 1) {
          // number of frigates in play
          System.out.println("How many Friggates would you like");
          button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String frigsString = textField1.getText();
              int frigs = Integer.parseInt(frigsString);
              for (int i = 0; i < frigs; i++) {
                ship.add(new Ship("Frig", 2));
                CPUship.add(new CPUShip("Frig", 2));
                System.out.println("Added Frig");
              }
              label1.setText("How many Battleships would you like");

            }
            state = 2;

          });
        }


        if (state == 2) {
          // number of battle ships in play
          button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              System.out.println("How many Battleships would you like");
              String battleshipsString = textField1.getText();
              int battleships = Integer.parseInt(battleshipsString);
              for (int i = 0; i < battleships; i++) {
                ship.add(new Ship("Battleship", 3));
                CPUship.add(new CPUShip("Battleship", 3));
                System.out.println("Added Battleship");
              }
              label1.setText("Done");
            }
          });
          state = 3;
        }
        if (state == 3) {
          System.out.println("Done");
```

The problem is when i run the code it appears to jump ahead of where it should, so printed to the console is "How many Submarines would you like How many Friggates would you like" immediately and the label is "How many subs would you like", once I enter 1 into the textfield and click the submit button the label changes to "how many Friggates would you like" and the console prints "How many Battleships would you like Added Battleship Added Frig Added Sub" then every time I press submit again the same thing happens just printing the 4 results.

I think this is because I have never actually quit out of the actionListener and so haven't done the equivalent of a break statement to stop it running although I may be incorrect. I have added in the state and if statements to see if I could solve the problem although it hasn't helped so they could be removed no problem.

Thanks in advance and apologies for such a long post.

Comment: Did you actually include the above code in a while(true) block, which is executed each frame ?

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand what you mean, I have a JPanel with Several frames the textfield is in one frame and the button in another frame, I don't have any while statements though? @felix.infinite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you only need to addActionListener(...) once on the button1 like this:

```
state = 0 // state is initialized to 0
label1.setText("How many Submarines would you like");
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         switch(getState()){
              case 0:
                    //Your How-many-submarines logic goes here

                    label1.setText("How many Friggates would you like");
                    setState(1);
                    break;
              case 1:
                    // Your how-many-friggates logic goes here
                     label1.setText("How many Battleships would you like");
                     setState(2);
                     break;

              case 2:
                    // Your how-many-battleships logic goes here
                    label1.setText("Done");
                    setState(3);
                    break;

              case 3:
                    System.out.println("Done");

         }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's definitely a good answer I'll up vote once I get enough reputation. The issue I have though is when I declare int state; then later down initialise the state to 0 that works fine but then the state statements in the switch statement want me to set state to final which I obviously can not do as the value is changing. If I set state to 0 and final initially the error I get from all the other "state = x" is "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable state defined in an enclosing scope".

Comment: Then you should access and change your state via get and set method in the anonymous inner class: implement void setState(int state) and int getState() in your current class.